# How to prioritize tilde (non-breaking space) over hyphen (breaking space)

Tags: line-breaking, tilde

I am using a tilde in the defined `\quoteboxtable` because I do not want a line break to occur between the dash and the name of the person being quoted. However, justification of the line is taking priority over my non-breaking space. While I do not want the column to be ragged right in general, I do not mind if the last line of the quote is not justified, so long as the tilde is respected. How can I prioritize the non-breaking space over the justification?

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand{\quoteboxtable}[2]{\textit{``#2''}\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{ -~#1}}
\begin{document}


\begin{table}

    \begin{tabular}{p{0.18\linewidth}p{0.73\linewidth}}

    Abcdefghijkl 
    & \quoteboxtable{Someone}{a bcdefghij klmno pqrstuv wxyza bc de fghi. Jkl mn o pqrstuvw  xyzabcdefghij klmno, pqr stu vwxyzabc.}\\
    
    \end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

The example produces:

[image: Incorrect line break]

Answer (score 4):

You are adding an explicit break point before the `~` with `-`, you can use `\mbox{-}` for a non-breaking hyphen

```
\documentclass[10pt,conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newcommand{\quoteboxtable}[2]{\textit{``#2''}\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{ \mbox{-}~#1}}
\begin{document}


\begin{table}

    \begin{tabular}{p{0.18\linewidth}p{0.73\linewidth}}

    Abcdefghijkl 
    & \quoteboxtable{Someone}{a bcdefghij klmno pqrstuv wxyza bc de fghi. Jkl mn o pqrstuvw  xyzabcdefghij klmno, pqr stu vwxyzabc.}\\
    
    \end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that solved it!